# EasyPHP - Apache and Mysql won't start (it was working yesterday)

Tags: mysql, apache, easyphp

I am working on my wordpress website and I use EasyPHP to run it locally. I tried to run Apache and Mysql this morning but when I hit the start button it spins and come back to the "start"....

- [Apache infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcDIg.png)
- [Mysql infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx91k.png)

MySQL Logs :

```html
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [Note] ..\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x161008194102\bin\eds-dbserver.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 6036 ...
```

Apache Logs :

```html
[Wed Feb 15 23:33:06.210769 2017] [:error] [pid 2540:tid 1160] [client 127.0.0.1:65526] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\\eds-www\\cafe-frejus\\wp-includes\\class-wp-dependency.php on line 19, referer: http://127.0.0.1/cafe-frejus/wp-admin/admin.php?page=revslider&view=slider&id=2
[Thu Feb 16 00:14:12.704129 2017] [:error] [pid 2540:tid 1124] [client 127.0.0.1:51093] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\\eds-www\\cafe-frejus\\wp-includes\\cron.php on line 27, referer: http://127.0.0.1/cafe-frejus/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Sage&tab=14
[Thu Feb 16 00:16:13.376084 2017] [:error] [pid 2540:tid 1160] [client 127.0.0.1:51102] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\\eds-www\\cafe-frejus\\wp-includes\\cron.php on line 27, referer: http://127.0.0.1/cafe-frejus/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Sage&tab=14
[Thu Feb 16 00:16:23.478629 2017] [:error] [pid 2540:tid 1124] [client 127.0.0.1:51103] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\\eds-www\\cafe-frejus\\wp-includes\\bookmark-template.php on line 51, referer: http://127.0.0.1/cafe-frejus/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

Thanks for your help!
B.

Answer (score 1):

So, Since I could't fix easyPHP, I decided to reinstall. However, I still need to get my website back.

---- Disclaimer : this may not be a good practice or a very elegant solution, if you have anything better please let me know :)  ----

Since I didn't back up the DB from PHPmyadmin, I tried the following :

1. Download EasyPHP (same version as before)
2. Install EasyPHP in program files (instead of program files (x86) )
3. Copy my wordpress folder from C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\myWPfolder to C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\myWPfolder
4. Copy the BD from C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x161008194102\data\myBDfolder to C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x161008194102\data\myBDfolder
   5 start Easy PHP from C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1 (so it is the new install)
5. Go in my browser and go to http://127.0.0.1/mywebsite

It works (so far)!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy to debug with the information here but the one error

```
2017-02-16T02:03:52.129737Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
```

is really the issue here if you ask me.

I think your installation is having issues with permissions. Try running it as an administrator?